# Explanation of Honeypot diagram

Tags: honeypot

Can someone please give me an exact explanation of what is happening in the diagram below? I have tried to find a diagram explaining the honeypot process but I can't seem to find a clear explanation.

In the below diagram I understand that a separate network is created in a demilitarized zone (DMZ), but I don't know what the role of the service router is in the diagram.

[image]

Link to image: https://www.blacksintechnology.net/an-overview-of-honeypots/

Comment: This is only one way to implement a honeypot, there are dozens of other ways to do it. If you are thinking this is definitive of honeypots, it is not. Second, the link is not related to your image at all. Third, you seem to understand what a DMZ is, so I'm confused why you are confused by the placement of the router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The role of the service router in this diagram is simply the router that separates two networks, the WAN (internet) and LAN (internal network). Additionally, the router has been configured to also point to a DMZ machine which will act as the honeypot for any new incoming connections that are not defined in the routing tables or firewall rules. If a DMZ was not defined in the router, these connections would be dropped instead.